# How to detect change in firebase by using android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, arduino-uno

My Arduino-Uno(this chip is not related to this question) sends either one of two values to **firebase**, **1 or 0**, I want it so that every time the value in the database is updated, it gets detected in android studio and it checks if the value updated is one

I don't particularly require a block of code, I just need to know the concept of this part. I want my app to check for the value even if the app is closed, for which which I did find something on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want my app to check for the value even if the app is closed

That does not seem hard. You can use a `Service` class and then do the event listener task there. Since you haven't asked for any code, I won't share it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46618432/17133283) is a good post on it